# Http calls in background for Angular Applications

Tags: angular, http

In my angular application, I have a page that need to do an HTTP call before rendering the view. The problem is that this HTTP call can be quite long (between 5 to 10 seconds).

What I would like to do is to start this HTTP call directly when my user is in the Welcome page so my Data are ready when the user navigate to the concerned page.

Is there a way to achieve that kind of behavior on Angular ?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. When your app starts it will always go through the AppComponent. Just put your call for the needed data right into the `ngOnInit()` method.

You just have to find a way to provide the loaded information to the user when he switches to the target page.

But this is pretty simple either. Just build up a service in which you store the result from the call. When the user then enters the target component, load the information directly from the service.

To make it round put the method for the backend call straight into this particular service and make it callable. So ngOnInit() of your AppComponent will just trigger the calling method inside your service, the service will store the result when it has arrived and the target component can access the data by calling another method of your service.

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

If you make an Angular Service (root scoped) and have that Service make the api call it will fire as soon as the user enters the app on any page. Do remember though that an observable will not fire until there is a subscriber, so subscribe in the constructor and store the result in a variable on the service.

I would not recommend using this as a pattern in a large app but for a one off small app there should be no issues.

Comment: That seems like a plan ! A question thought, what pattern would you use in a larger app ?

Comment: The issue would be if you did this for 20 different requests they would all fire on first load and hurt performance. I would recommend any popular state management library for angular like NgRx, or using the angular route resolvers to share data.

Answer (score 1):

Angular Resolve Features make sense...

Befor rendering server call data...

Or

Route configuration with data property make sense for static data

Please comment if any other ways...